# Добавление полей сущности EF динамически

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Есть модель EF сгенерированная на основе бд. В этой модели есть некоторые поля, которые содержат метаданные (например имя того, кто создал или изменил запись).
Т.к. в модели все поля метаданных имеют одинковые имена, то устанавливаю я эти значения при помощи рефлексии в обработчике события ObjectContext.SavingChanges. Это очень удобно, так как здесь я имею всю необходимую информацию о том, какие записи изменяются и какие новые:

```
var addedEntries = ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(System.Data.EntityState.Added);
```

или

```
var modifiedEntries = ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(System.Data.EntityState.Modified);
```

В новой версии базы данных добавляются новые поля для метаданных. Необходимо не обновляя модель EF установить некоторые значения этим полям. При этом программа должна работать как со старой версией бд, так и с новой.

Возникла идея добавления полей EF сущностям динамически в этом же обработчике события SavingChanges и затем устанавливать их значения.

Можно ли такое делать? как?

Comment: Если честно, выглядит страшно. Обычно таки EF и прочие ORM используются для маппинга типизированных объектов, чтобы вообще не думать о базе и каком то там хранении объектов. Положил и достал, всё. Вы же пытаетесь работать как то нестандартно, да ещё и сразу с двумя версиями базы одной версией приложения. Я бы приложение тогда тоже на версии делил.

Comment: Спасибо за коментарий, но мне нужно решить задачу в описанном ключе

Comment: _"имею всю необходимую информацию о том, какие записи изменяются и какие новые"_ -- а почему не используете DbContext.ChangeTracker и IEntityWithChangeTracker?

Comment: Может быть можно реализовать задуманное при помощи наследования? Наследующая сущность будет иметь новые поля. В приложении в зависимости от версии базы данных используется или базовая сущность или ее наследник. Стоит развивать идею в этом направлении?